# Is there a way to get the mean for roughly a year given a particular date?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, mean

I have a dataset (DF1) with dates (i.e. month and year in two separate columns) along with a count per month and a group ID. I have another data set (DF2) with birthdays (separated into day, month, year into 3 columns) and group ID. What I would like to do is for each member belonging to a certain group (from DF2), find the mean group count for 12 months starting from its birthday (included in DF1) and add it to a new column in DF2.

I would like to learn to use loops, however, if there is a simpler method, I would use that too. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I mentioned "roughly a year" because the first few years dont have all 12 months. However, after the first 2-3 years, all months are included

Comment: This could be done using data.table [non-equi joins](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/the-unequalled-joy-of-non-equi-joins/). please `dput` a part of DF1 and DF2 if you aren't sure how this would be done.

Comment: you will get more helpful answers if you visualize your problem with 2 data.frames / tibble as compact as possible. Like 3*3 or 4*4 sizes